# Flutter: How to fetch (all) of a child data from firebase realtime database in streambuilder/futurebuilder with ListViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch all of the child('users') data from realtime database in a StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder through out a ListView.builder(), but unfortunately it always returns null!

So how can i do it?

Here is what i have tried to do:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';


class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("users");

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: dbRef.once(),
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
final userS = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: userS.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i)=> Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child:  Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(userS[i]['username']),
                    Text(userS[i]['password'])
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            );
        }
        return const Center(child: Text('There is something wrong!'),);
      },
      );
  }
}
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOdN1.png)

Comment: Please include the error message as text in your question. Including screenshots should really only be done for things that can't be captured in text (like a screenshot of a layout issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in your app:

```
final userS = snapshot.data!.snapshot.value
```

You're taking the value of the [`DataSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html), which in your case is going to be a `Map<String, dynamic>`. And a `Map` doesn't have an `[]` accessor, which is why you get an error.

If you want to get the results by index, it's probably easier to keep the `DataSnapshot`:

```
final userS = snapshot.data!.snapshot;
```

And then access its `children` by their index:

```
children: [
  Text(userS.children.toList()[i].child('username').value),
  Text(userS.children.toList()[i].child('password').value)
],
```

So here we use `userS.children.toList()` to get the child snapshots into a list, and then look up the correct snapshot by its index. From there we can then get the value of its `username` and `password` child properties.

Comment: it has returned this error: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' has no instance getter 'children'.
Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:5
Tried calling: children

Comment: If you check the link to `DataSnapshot` in my answer, you'll see that it has a `children` property. It sounds like you still are getting the `.value` in the `userS` assignment, instead of setting that to just the `DataSnapshot` as I show in the second code snippet of my answer.

Comment: First of all i wanna thank you frank you helped me before and it really worked and this time also you're 100% correct, but the issue here that what i actually have is in the ListView.builder(), when we remove (value) from userS it's going return a length error because the itemCount take the userS.length, here is the error: Class 'DataSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DataSnapshot'
Tried calling: length

Comment: Frank as you did last time you gave me a tip and i kept searching and coding till i found the solution just like the last one. THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANK you from the bottom of my heart <3. here is the solution in itemCount :userS.children.toList().length, then i added the codes you referred to me in the Text widget, Oh! thank God this one took me a whole day almost 15 hours

Comment: Ah. interesting. I should've though of it using the `length`. In that case it's probably better to use `final userS = snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList()` and simplify the code in the item builder too.

Comment: I will do that for sure, but now what i'm trying to do is getting the userID from userS how can i do that? as far what i have done and it has returned an error is this:  GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            UserDetailScreen.routeName, 
                            arguments: userSnapshot.children.id,
                            );
                        },

Comment: here is the error it returned: Class 'MappedListIterable<DataSnapshotPlatform, DataSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'id'.
Receiver: Instance of 'MappedListIterable<DataSnapshotPlatform, DataSnapshot>'
Tried calling: id